# How to parse Text File to Array line by line?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, text-files, filereader

I have problem with my script. I don't know how to put text into array line by line :((

**Text File**

```
Bob
Marc
Will
Tony
```

**Output**

```
Array[0:"Bob", 1:"Marc", 3:"Will", 3:"Tony"]
```

How I can achieve this output???

***I tried something like this...***

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

input.addEventListener(
  "change",
  function(e) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      const lines = reader.result.split(" ");
      let array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
        array.push(lines[i]);
      }
      console.log(array);
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
  },
  false
);
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Do you have any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: what is the result of the example of what you tried above?

Comment: You can't have duplicate index 3 in an array.

Comment: are you using node ?

Comment: No, it's not Node. This is local javascript.

Comment: Result of code which I used look like this=> Array [0: "Bob, Marc, Will, Tony"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split("\n")` to use newline as the delimiter, not a space.

You don't have to copy the array with the `for` loop.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

input.addEventListener(
  "change",
  function(e) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      const lines = reader.result.split("\n");
      console.log(lines);
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
  },
  false
);
```

```html
<input type="file">
```